# comparing current time in milliseconds to time saved in shared preferences

Tags: java, android, time, sharedpreferences

I've shared my current time in sharedPreferences using the following method:

Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("DataCountService", 0);
long millis = date.getTime();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putLong("smstimestamp", date.getTime());
editor.commit();
```

Now (later in the source code at a later date) I need to compare the current time to the time I saved in shared preferences to see if 30 days has elapsed.

What is the best method of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1st of all, on this line you should change to:

```
editor.putLong("smstimestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

there's no need to create a date and then get the millis again.

now to compare it:

```
//             milli min  hour  day 30day
long days_30 = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("DataCountService", 0);
long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp");
if(System.currentTimeMillis() - oldTime > days_30){
      // here, more than 30 days
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 

P.S.

I'm getting an error stating "The method getLong(String, long) in the type SharedPreferences is not applicable for the arguments (String)"  - any suggestions?

Comment: You need to pass also default value as a second argument.