# How to display welcome screen only one time in a day on android?

Tags: android

How to display welcome screen only one time in a day on android? I am preparing a screen with emojis rain fall and Iwant to display it only once in a day when the app is opened for the first time.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EmojiRainLayout emojiRainLayout;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        emojiRainLayout = (EmojiRainLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                emojiRainLayout.addEmoji(R.drawable.bell);
                emojiRainLayout.addEmoji(R.drawable.coconut);
                emojiRainLayout.addEmoji(R.drawable.deepam);
                emojiRainLayout.addEmoji(R.drawable.flower);
                emojiRainLayout.addEmoji(R.drawable.folded);

                emojiRainLayout.stopDropping();
                emojiRainLayout.setPer(4);
                emojiRainLayout.setDuration(7200);
                emojiRainLayout.setDropDuration(2400);
                emojiRainLayout.setDropFrequency(500);
                emojiRainLayout.startDropping();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Keep a time stamp when the screen was last shown (for example in preferences). Show the screen only when the saved time stamp is older than say 24h. Alternatively, you could check if the date of time stamp is different from today's date.

Comment: I am very new to programming can you plz help me how to do.

Comment: what exactly is a problem for you? Which part of suggested approach?

Comment: You can use sharedPreferences or sqlite to store current date. Every time android application is opened check whether stored date is less than today date, if it is then show the emoji rain splash screen and update the sharedPreference and sqlite with today date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201937/5502638 u can modify this as per your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you first show it,save currentTime into SharedPreferences,like save System.currentTimeMillis() as t1,
2. For second time ,get current time t2 by System.currentTimeMillis() ,
3. Read your t1,and get day1 and day2 by new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") from t1 and t2,
4. Compare day1 and day2,if day2 bigger than day1 then show it and update your t1 in SharedPreference or day1 and day2 is same then do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
long time = sharedPrefs.getLong("displayedTime", 0);
if(time == 0 || time < System.currentTimeMillis() - 259200000) // 259200000 (Millisecond) = 24 Hours
{
    // Show welcome screen
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putLong("displayedTime", System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
    prefsEditor.apply();
}
```

Comment: I showed my screen through intent. Is it the right way.

Comment: Yes. You can use intent.

Comment: then why its not showing in one time, when i reopen the app it is showing again.

Comment: I edited my answer, (*Edit* : `time < System.currentTimeMillis()`)

Answer (score 0):

//In onCreate

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();    //get current date.
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());

    String currentDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    boolean showWelcome = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("isShowWelcomeScreen", false);
    if (showWelcome) {// normal flow
        String appOpenDate = sharedpreferences.getString("appOpenDate", "");
        boolean flag = compareDate(currentDate, appOpenDate);
        if (!flag) {
            //show welcome screen.
        }
    } else {
        //show welcome screen.
        //In Welcome screen activity/ fragment.
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("appOpenDate", currentDate); //save date when app open
        editor.putBoolean("isShowWelcomeScreen", true);
        editor.apply();
    }
```